# keytool Error for Map API Key

Tags: android, android-mapview

How to publish the Apk file with signed key for Map,
Am Getting Error as Follows in CMD

**C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\jre\bin>keytool -list -v -keystore D:\Shankar
Completed Project\Mandate Project\keystore -alias mandatehandbook
Illegal option:  Completed
keytool -list [OPTION]...**

Lists entries in a keystore

Options:

Use **"keytool -help"** for all available commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put quotes around the keystore path.  Your shell is confused by the space in the pathname.

```
keytool -list -v -keystore "D:\Shankar Completed Project\Mandate Project\keystore" -alias mandatehandbook
```

Comment: and if there are multiple aliases, you also have to enclose them in quotes

Answer (score 0):

**debug keytool example:**

```
keytool -list -v -keystore "D:\Users\%your name%\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```